# My dropdown menu that I created with django-mptt and bootstrap 5.3 is not showed up on my template , how can I fix it?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, bootstrap-5

My dropdown menu that I created with django-mptt and bootstrap 5.3 is not showed up on my template , how can I fix it??? I tried a lot to fix this but I can't, can anyone help please ?
This is my template code :

```
div class="dropdown">

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            {% recursetree categories %}

                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"

                        aria-expanded="false">

                    {{ node.name }}

                </button>

                

                <li {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}class="dropdown-submenu"{% endif %}>

                    <a class="dropdown-item {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}dropdown-toggle{% endif %}"

                       href="{% if node.is_leaf_node %}{{ node.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}"

                       {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"{% endif %}>

                        {{ node.name }}

                        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}<span class="dropdown-caret"></span>{% endif %}

                    </a>

                    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            {{ children }}

                        </ul>

                    {% endif %}

                </li>

            {% endrecursetree %}

        </ul>
```

And this is my views.py

```
class HomePage(View):

    def get(self, request, ):

        postss = Post.objects.all()

        categories = Category.objects.all()

        form = CategoryForm()

        return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'postss': postss, 'categories': categories, 'form': form})
```

And this is a js code for this dropdown

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var dropdownSubmenus = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-submenu'));

    dropdownSubmenus.forEach(function(submenu) {

        submenu.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {

            this.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.add('show');

        });

        submenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {

            this.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.remove('show');

        });

    });

});
```

It's just not work idk why

It's showing up the dropdown codes correct in inspect but not showing up in template